# Change Nested Span class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues changing the span class when it's nested inside the button element with Javascript.

I am trying to make it appear like this http://www.bootply.com/128062# and I have verified the CSS works.

**HTML**

```
<button id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" onclick="onclickFunction();">
    <span id ="submit_span" class=""></span> Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function onclickFunction() {
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'btn btn-lg btn-warning';
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    document.getElementById('submit_span').className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're destroying the `<span>` element when you write to the `.innerHTML` of the button.

Instead, select the `.lastChild` of the button, and updates its `.data` *(assuming that's where you wanted the text to go)*.

```
function onclickFunction() {
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'btn btn-lg btn-warning';
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').lastChild.data = 'Loading...';
    document.getElementById('submit_span').className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate';
}
```

---

Your code would be shorter and cleaner if you just passed `this` into the function.

```js
function onclickFunction(btn) {
  // The button element
  btn.className = 'btn btn-lg btn-warning';

  // The last text node in the button
  btn.lastChild.data = 'Loading...';

  // The first element (span) in the button
  btn.firstElementChild.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate';
}
```

```css
.btn.btn-lg.btn-warning {
  background: orange
}

.glyphicon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="onclickFunction(this);" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">
  <span id="submit_span" class="">x</span> Submit
</button>
```

Adjust the elements that are updated as needed. Not sure where exactly you expected stuff to go.

Comment: I have tried both solutions and I am still getting the same problem

Comment: @user3263650: I turned my second example into a working demo, though I changed `btn.firstChild` into `btn.firstElementChild` since I had forgotten about the whitespace before the `<span>`. Clicking the button works.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sequence should be this:

```
function onclickFunction() {
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'btn btn-lg btn-warning';
    document.getElementById('submit_span').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    document.getElementById('submit_span').className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that squint provided was not far off but was not correct. I had to change it too this.
**Previous**

```
// The first element (span) in the button

btn.firstChild.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate';
```

**After**

```
btn.firstElementChild.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate';
```

I found this out by going in chrome,inspect element,inspect DOM properties, expand the button in the console and you will see firstElementChild.